# Android sync sql lite db with external database

Tags: android, database

Good evening.

I am working on an Android project that needs to connect an SQL Lite DB to and external DB. I already did that and it works fine, but now I want to do something different. Because the Android isn't always connected to the internet, I need to send the new information to the external database and I thought of doing something like this:
    If the app is connected to the internet (when new data is available), it will send the data to the external DB and also save it in the local DB. In the local DB I have a Date field that is null if the information hasn't been sent yet, or has the value of when the data was sent. 
    If I don't have an internet connection when new data is available, the data is only going to be saved in the android DB. When the app starts, it checks if it is connected to the internet and sends the data that hasn't been sent yet.

I also would like that at least once a day, the app would try to update the external DB automatically (without user interaction). I was advised to use this http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html but after some research it seems that few people use it.

What do you think? Are there other ways or some good up-to-date tutorials that you can refer?
Thanks